# Fastest way to check if two arrays have equivalent rows

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to figure out a better way to check if two 2D arrays contain the same rows. Take the following case for a short example:

```
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
>>> b
array([[6, 7, 8],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2]])
```

In this case `b=a[::-1]`. To check if two rows are equal:

```
>>>a=a[np.lexsort((a[:,0],a[:,1],a[:,2]))]
>>>b=b[np.lexsort((b[:,0],b[:,1],b[:,2]))]
>>> np.all(a-b==0)
True
```

This is great and fairly fast. However the issue comes about when two rows are "close":

```
array([[-1.57839867  2.355354   -1.4225235 ],
       [-0.94728367  0.         -1.4225235 ],
       [-1.57839867 -2.355354   -1.4225215 ]]) <---note ends in 215 not 235
array([[-1.57839867 -2.355354   -1.4225225 ],
       [-1.57839867  2.355354   -1.4225225 ],
       [-0.94728367  0.         -1.4225225 ]])
```

Within a tolerance of 1E-5 these two arrays are equal by row, but the lexsort will tell you otherwise. This can be solved by a different sorting order but I would like a more general case.

I was toying with the idea of:

```
a=a.reshape(-1,1,3)
>>> a-b
array([[[-6, -6, -6],
        [-3, -3, -3],
        [ 0,  0,  0]],

       [[-3, -3, -3],
        [ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 3,  3,  3]],

       [[ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 3,  3,  3],
        [ 6,  6,  6]]])
>>> np.all(np.around(a-b,5)==0,axis=2)
array([[False, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
>>>np.all(np.any(np.all(np.around(a-b,5)==0,axis=2),axis=1))
True
```

This doesn't tell you if the arrays are equal by row just if all points in `b` are close to a value in `a`. The number of rows can be several hundred and I need to do it quite a bit. Any ideas?

Comment: I will throw in `scipy.spatial.cKDTree` (possibly KDTree, depending on scipy version and usage), for an approach, which might be more straight forward.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Knew there had to be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last code doesn't do what you think it is doing. What it tells you is whether every row in `b` is close to a row in `a`. If you change the `axis` you use for the outer calls to `np.any` and `np.all`, you could check whether every row in `a` is close to some row in `b`. If both every row in `b` is close to a row in `a`, and every row in `a` is close to a row in `b`, then the sets are equal. Probably not very computationally efficient, but probably very fast in numpy for moderately sized arrays:

```
def same_rows(a, b, tol=5) :
    rows_close = np.all(np.round(a - b[:, None], tol) == 0, axis=-1)
    return (np.all(np.any(rows_close, axis=-1), axis=-1) and
            np.all(np.any(rows_close, axis=0), axis=0))

>>> rows, cols = 5, 3
>>> a = np.arange(rows * cols).reshape(rows, cols)
>>> b = np.arange(rows)
>>> np.random.shuffle(b)
>>> b = a[b]
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14]])
>>> b
array([[ 9, 10, 11],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [12, 13, 14]])
>>> same_rows(a, b)
True
>>> b[0] = b[1]
>>> b
array([[ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [12, 13, 14]])
>>> same_rows(a, b) # not all rows in a are close to a row in b
False
```

And for not too big arrays, performance is reasonable, even though it is having to build an array of `(rows, rows, cols)`:

```
In [2]: rows, cols = 1000, 10

In [3]: a = np.arange(rows * cols).reshape(rows, cols)

In [4]: b = np.arange(rows)

In [5]: np.random.shuffle(b)

In [6]: b = a[b]

In [7]: %timeit same_rows(a, b)
10 loops, best of 3: 103 ms per loop
```

Comment: I did mention that was one issue with the code the I posted. This is essentially I ended up writing with a few additional arguments. I added in a distance formula to give a better idea of how close a point was and used the lexsort method to drastically reduce the number of rows that needed to be passed to this type of check. I will check your answer if nobody comes up with a better idea by tomorrow.